# Custom login process with python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-social-auth, django-pipeline

I am using a very custom login process, with email/password forms there's no problem. I am using redis to store the session.
I know that I can configure `SESSION_ENGINE` in my `settings.py` file and Django will do this even with `python-social-auth` login, but I need to write my own session key and value, because I am using `jwt`, I also need to do some other custom action in login process, so I have been looking for a while how to 'intercept' the login process in the python-social-auth flow, I have checked the code for every pipeline but I couldn't find out where is this happening. How can I implement a custom login with `python-social-auth`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try great `django-rest-social-auth` (https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) which uses `python-social-auth`, `django-rest-framework` and also `djangorestframework-jwt` modules (the last one implements JWT support). If it's not suits you, you can discover the code of `django-rest-social-auth` and `djangorestframework-jwt` to implement your own flow.